# How to generate multiple values of CSS property using SCSS?

Tags: sass

How to generate the following CSS in SCSS for given count `n`?

```css
background-image:
  linear-gradient(#FFF 1, transparent 0),
  linear-gradient(#FFF 2, transparent 0),
  ...
  linear-gradient(#FFF n, transparent 0);

background-position:
  0px center,
  1px center,
  ...
  npx center;
```

(This is just a simple useless example for demonstration.)

Comment: It's probably downvoted because you don't explain the attempts you've made to answer your question yourself. It might also be because it has been asked multiple time on Stackoverflow. You can find a good documentation on the scss website itself, check [the @for loop on sass-lang](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for/)

Comment: I know @for loop, but I did not know how to use it for non-string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a [function](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/function/) containing a [for-loop](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/for/) to build up a [list](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/lists/) by [appending](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/list/#append) a new comma separated value in each iteration.

```scss
@function gradient-n($n){
  $sequence: ();
  @for $i from 1 through $n {
    $new: linear-gradient(#FFF $i, transparent 0);
    $sequence: append($sequence, $new, comma);
  }
  @return $sequence;
}


.foo {
    background-image: gradient-n(5);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, could also be a `@mixin` that would do both the positioning and the image. Something like:   
```@mixin gradient($n){
    $gradient: "";
    $position: "";
    @for $i from 0 through $n {
        $gradient: $gradient + "linear-gradient(#FFF #{$i}, transparent 0),";
        $position: $position + "#{$i}px center,"
    }  
    background-image: $gradient;
    background-position: $position;
}```

Comment: For other readers: I found another way using strings and `unquote()`. But lists fit better.